# Issue with JSQMessages Displaying Test Messages

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

When I add multiple test messages, only two of them are displaying on screen. The other messages are clearly there because I can copy them, but the colors are simply not showing. When I scroll around, a new two texts appear, but it is still only two. Below show some examples.

[image: This image shows when the screen first loads.]

[image: This image shows the screen after I've scrolled around for a bit.]

[image: This image shows that the messages are clearly there, but that the bubbles are not showing up.]

First screenshot shows when the screen first loads. second shows when I move it around. Third shows that the other messages do exist but are not visible. Any ideas on how to fix this? Also, how do I make the names appear? Is there a good guide to doing this in Swift?

Here is the code I used:

```
    var messages = [JSQMessage]()

var incomingBubbleImageView = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory.incomingMessageBubbleImageViewWithColor(UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleLightGrayColor())
var outgoingBubbleImageView = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory.outgoingMessageBubbleImageViewWithColor(UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleGreenColor())

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.sender = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString

    messages += [JSQMessage(text: "hello", sender: self.sender)]
    messages += [JSQMessage(text: "hello", sender: "other")]
    messages += [JSQMessage(text: "hello", sender: self.sender)]
    messages += [JSQMessage(text: "hello", sender: "other")]
    messages += [JSQMessage(text: "hello", sender: self.sender)]
    messages += [JSQMessage(text: "hello", sender: "other")]

    reloadMessagesView()

}

func reloadMessagesView() {
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

And here is the extension code for the delegate methods:

```
extension TestJSQ {

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(self.messages.count)
    return self.messages.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    let data = self.messages[indexPath.row]
    return data
}
```

//    override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, didDeleteMessageAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
//        self.messages.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, bubbleImageViewForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UIImageView {

    let data = messages[indexPath.row]
    switch(data.sender) {
    case self.sender:
        return self.outgoingBubbleImageView
    default:
        return self.incomingBubbleImageView
    }

    }

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageViewForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UIImageView! {
    return nil
}
```

}

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: You should invalidate the layout before reloading data. I'm not sure about the equivalent in swift, but in Objective-C you do: `[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayoutWithContext:[JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext context]];` before calling `[self.collectionView reloadData];`

Comment: I tried that, but that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Is that all the code for your subclass of `JSQMessagesViewController`? Do you implement `viewWillAppear` and/or `viewDidAppear` if so, can you check if you're calling the appropriate `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` or `[super viewDidAppear:animated]` swift counterpart?

Comment: By the way, for the other part of your question about the names, you can use `collectionView:attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath:` method from the `JSQMessagesCollectionViewDataSource`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `self.finishReceivingMessage()` after you add the message(s) to the data source (which will then invalidate layout BEFORE call `collectionView.reloadData()` for you)